# Запущенно несколько процессов одного приложения ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis, asp

У меня есть веб приложение на ASP MVC Framework опубликованное на IIS 10. В нем есть ряд джобов работающие через Quartz. Недавно я стал замечать что некоторые джобы стали отрабатывать по несколько раз, например задач отослать уведомление на почту в 7 утра могла выполниться два, а то и больше раз. И так почти со всеми. Когда захотел присоединиться к процессу, обнаружил что там запущенно несколько управляемых, которые каждый работает по отдельности. то есть перед исполнением джоба присоединившись к одному процессу и приостановив его, у меня выполнились остальные, а потом ещё и тот к которому присоединился, после его высвобождении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таких процессов может быть разное количество, иногда доходило до 8. В самом  IIS показывает только одно приложение, и при запуске приложения через IIS Express тоже всё работает хорошо.
ОС Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормально. В настройках апппула есть опция - количество одновременно запускаемых процессов. В asp.net нужно быть готовым к тому, что процесса может вообще не быть (если апппул заснул по неактивном и), так и быть больше, чем задано в свойствах апппула (при overlapping recycle) например.

Если вам нужна надёжная фоновая обработка - выносите ее или в win service, или в что-то, что будет запускаться по внешнему расписанию (через task scheduler, например). Quartz.net и другие чисто asp.net решения ненадёжны.

Comment: Эта "ненадежность" - она относится к asp.net или к IIS? Есть ли такие же подводные камни в asp.net core? Например, если хостить его не в IIS?

Comment: @tym32167 только к IIS и его модели app pools. В core не под IIS - приложение - это просто консолька, надежнее некуда :)

Comment: Ну это как посмотреть. Например, если в пуле процесс отвалится от, например, переполнения стека, то пул процесс сам заново поднимет. В консольке наверное такого не случится.

Comment: @tym32167 консольку поднимет Kubernetes. Правда для него проблема  overlapping recycle тоже будет актуальна (в виде rolling deployments). Вобщем, лучше веб хостить отдельно, job-ы - отдельно.